# Flutter missing common directory

Tags: flutter, installation, path, sdk

I used snap to install flutter on an Ubuntu (Kubuntu) 19.04 disco. I've done the following:

```
sudo snap install flutter --classic
sudo snap install flutter-gallery
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
flutter config --enable-linux-desktop
```

credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62939783/11596178

However, for some reason, my flutter folder in snap does not contain a "common" directory.

```
/snap/flutter$ ls
22  current
```

This is a problem because it is to my understanding that the SDK should be in `/home/(username)/snap/flutter/common/flutter`

Where is my flutter SDK if the common folder does not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong directory. It's a bit confusing, but there's
/snap which is from your root directory, and then there's /home/[insert your username]/snap/flutter.

The directory you should be looking for is
/home/[username]/snap/flutter/common/flutter

Notice that the path to the flutter git repository and SDK is the one that contains your username. It should not be the one that is found at the root directory. i.e. /snap/flutter/

Comment: Perhaps not worthy of being an answer, but in my case I had simply forgot to run flutter for the first time. When you run this command those home based directories actually get configured for you.