# Flutter SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, sdk

As an intern, I have been tasked with figuring out a certain codebase built on flutter. I keep running into this error. This is my first time doing anything flutter-wise.

Any help will be appreciated.

This is the error:

```
18:02   Gradle sync failed: Cause: flutter.sdk not set in local.properties. Expression: (flutterSdkPath != null). Values: flutterSdkPath = null (19 s 583 ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236128/how-to-find-the-path-of-flutter-sdk) and its answers for setting the Flutter SDK Path in Android Studio.